# XSLT Transformation Nested Loop of Multiple Child Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT transformation. I am stuck on a looping question and need some direction from the group.

This is my XML:

```
<OUTPUT>
    <VECTOR ID="6">
        <ELEMENT ID="1">
            <CLASS ID="12345">
                <OWNR_EMP>EMP1</OWNR_EMP>
                <OWNR_EMP_NUM>XXXX</OWNR_EMP_NUM>
            </CLASS>
        </ELEMENT>
        <ELEMENT ID="2">
            <CLASS ID="12345">
                <OWNR_EMP>EMP2</OWNR_EMP>
                <OWNR_EMP_NUM>YYYY</OWNR_EMP_NUM>
            </CLASS>
        </ELEMENT>
    </VECTOR>
    <VECTOR ID="6">
        <ELEMENT ID="1">
            <CLASS ID="54321">
                <EMP_ID>EMP1</EMP_ID>
                <EMP_DTLS>DTLS1</EMP_DTLS>
            </CLASS>
        </ELEMENT>
        <ELEMENT ID="2">
            <CLASS ID="54321">
                <EMP_ID>EMP2</EMP_ID>
                <EMP_DTLS>DTLS2</EMP_DTLS>
            </CLASS>
        </ELEMENT>
    </VECTOR>
</OUTPUT>
```

Here is the XSLT that I tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/OUTPUT/VECTOR/ELEMENT">

<xsl:variable name="empid_1"  select="CLASS/OWNR_EMP" />

<xsl:for-each select="CLASS">

<xsl:variable name="classid_2"  select="@ID" />

<xsl:if test="string($classid_2) = '12345' ">

<xsl:variable name="empid_2" select="OWNR_EMP" />

<xsl:if test="string($empid_2) = string($empid_1) ">

<EMP>

<OWNR_EMP><xsl:value-of select="OWNR_EMP" /></OWNR_EMP>

<OWNR_EMP_NUM><xsl:value-of select="OWNR_EMP_NUM" /></OWNR_EMP_NUM>

</EMP>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

 <xsl:if test="string($classid_2) = '54321' ">

<xsl:variable name="empid_3" select="EMP_ID" />

<xsl:if test="string($empid_3) = string($empid_1) ">

<EMP_DETAIL>

<EMP_ID><xsl:value-of select="EMP_ID" /></EMP_ID>

<EMP_DTLS><xsl:value-of select="EMP_DTLS" /></EMP_DTLS>

</EMP_DETAIL>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
```

My desired output:

```
<OUTPUT>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <EMP>
            <OWNR_EMP>EMP1</OWNR_EMP>
            <OWNR_EMP_NUM>XXXX</OWNR_EMP_NUM>
        </EMP>
        <EMP_DETAIL>
            <EMP_ID>EMP1</EMP_ID>
            <EMP_DTLS>DTLS1</EMP_DTLS>
        </EMP_DETAIL>
    </EMPLOYEE>
    <EMPLOYEE>
        <EMP>
            <OWNR_EMP>EMP2</OWNR_EMP>
            <OWNR_EMP_NUM>YYYY</OWNR_EMP_NUM>
        </EMP>
        <EMP_DETAIL>
            <EMP_ID>EMP2</EMP_ID> 
            <EMP_DTLS>DTLS2</EMP_DTLS>
        </EMP_DETAIL>
    </EMPLOYEE>
</OUTPUT>
```

VECTOR TAG contains multiple nodes of CLASS '12345' and '54321'.

ELEMENT 1 of first CLASS should combine with ELEMENT 1 of Second CLASS.

Comment: You can help us to help you by editing your question to show any XSLT you have currently tried. Thank you!

Comment: You say you're stuck, and we're very happy to help get you unstuck, but we don't know where you are stuck, so short of just writing the code for you (which isn't a great way of teaching anyone), it's very hard for us to help. Remember: StackOverflow is about questions and answers. You need to ask a question, not just issue a plea for help.

Comment: The example is ambiguous. Please explain in detail the logic that needs to applied here.

Comment: You may be stuck because you're approaching the problem in an imperative way; lots of ifs and looping. A declarative approach might be a better fit. Check out xsl:template and xsl:apply-templates. I'll try to add an example later.